# C++ and Python tight integrating

Tags: python, c++, integration

I have C++ program and I want to add extension system with Python. But to achieve this I have to map Python object method calls to C++ method calls. Is this possible and if yes how to achieve.

**Example**:
Python part:

```
class Extension(AbstractExtension):
    def __init__(self, cool_cpp_object):
        self.o = cool_cpp_object

    def some_method(self):
        self.o.method_to_cpp()
```

C++ part:

```
class SomeClass : public AnotherClass
{
public:
    void method_to_cpp();
}
```

I have to pass SomeClass instance to Extension instance method. Thankyou.

Comment: Give [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/exposing.html#tutorial.exposing.constructors) a go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways of doing so (StoryTeller correctly notes Boost::Python, and there is [Swig](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html) too). Personally, I find [Cython's C++ integration](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html) exceptionally easy to use.

Create some header file, say `classes.hpp`, and in it put (along with guards, etc.):

```
class SomeClass : public AnotherClass
{
public:
    void method_to_cpp();
}
```

Place the implementation in an implementation file the usual way.

Now create Cython file with an export of the interface you will use:

```
cdef extern from "classes.hpp":
cdef cppclass SomeClass:
    method_to_cpp()
```

and a Python wrapper:

```
cdef class PySomeClass:
     cdef SomeClass obj

     def method(self):
         self.obj.method_to_cpp()
```

That's it, basically. You can import and use `PySomeClass` like a regular Python class.

The link above should explain how to build all the files.

Comment: Ok, I skimmed link and it's realy very easy to integrate C++ to python but I still didn't get how to pass already created C++ object to Python.

Comment: @Megaxela It's a (Cython) member of `PySomeClass`, which you can pass around like a regular Python object. The other Python code can call members of `PySomeClass`, and its members can call the methods of the C++ object.